# Express Router middleware error (`app.use() requires a middleware function`)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I know there are many similar questions here, but I promise I've read all of them and didn't find a solution.

I'm trying to write an app using Express Router, but I'm getting this error:

`app.use() requires a middleware function`

I already tried to implement the middleware in many ways, but couldn't fix.

Here's the latest version of my code (which is very neat):

`/index.js`

```
import express from 'express';

const app = express();

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.method, req.url);
  next();
});

app.use(require('./routes'));
```

`/routes/index.js`

```
import credentials from './credentials';

export default [credentials];
```

`/routes/credentials/index.js`

```
import express from 'express';

const router = express.Router();

router.get('/credentials', async (req, res) => {
    console.log('Getting credentials...');
});

export default router;
```

Can anybody help me find the issue?

Comment: In routes/index file you're exporting an array having credentials as one item, but app.use is expecting a middleware function

Comment: @AbhaySehgal I'm actually passing an array to be added in `app.use` of my index. When I require directly `/routes/credentials/index.js` I get this error: `Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a Object`.

Comment: I think that's because nodejs use commonjs so you require to use module.export instead of export default

Comment: Replace export default router with module.export = router

Comment: @AbhaySehgal I just answered my own question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53927036/3799550. Thanks for your time anyways.

Answer (score 1):

I found the error. In my `/index.js`, I should have added my routes into a `router.use` instead of `app.use`.

Here's the final code of my `/index.js`:

```
import express from 'express';

const app = express();
const router = express.Router();

router.use(require('./routes'));
app.use(router);
```